# Not able add new line in yahoo mail message composing via anchor tag

Tags: email, anchor, href, yahoo

I am not able to add new line in body yahoo mail message composing via href tag.

Following is the anchor tag for yahoo mail:

```
<a href="http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?bcc=dem@gmail.com&amp;subj=demo subject&amp;body=demo text%0D%0A new line" target="_blank" data-role="none">demo link</a>
```

For gmail %0A is working fine for showing text in next line and br tag is working fine for hotmail.

But for yahoo and AOL I am not able find solution for showing text in next line?

Answer (score 0):

Your text links might get reformatted by Yahoo! shortcuts

Here is a link to a host of other nasty thing Yahoo mail will do and how to correct it:

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/9_ways_to_prevent_yahoo_headaches#yahoo_tip2